# Creating patch file for linux kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, diff, sudo

I am trying to create a patch file, for the modifications I have done in linux kernel. 
The original directory is **/usr/src/linux.vanilla** and the new kernel is **/usr/src/linux-master**.
The command I used is

```
h@ubuntu:/usr/src$ sudo diff -rupN  linux-master/ linux.vanilla/ > original.patch
```

However I get an error stating

```
bash: original.patch: Permission denied
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong. I am using Ubuntu and linux kernel version 3.15.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you typed into the terminal is this:

```
sudo diff -rupN  linux-master/ linux.vanilla/ > original.patch
```

This will run as root:

```
diff -rupN  linux-master/ linux.vanilla/
```

And then as your **normal user account**, it will write the output into

```
original.patch
```

However, you don't have write permissions to `original.patch`.

### Fix 1

Do the work under a root shell.

```
sudo su
diff -rupN  linux-master/ linux.vanilla/ > original.patch
```

### Fix 2

Use `tee` to redirect to a file.

```
sudo diff -rupN  linux-master/ linux.vanilla/ | sudo tee original.patch
```

### Fix 3

Write the file to your home directory (or some other location that you have write permissions).

```
sudo diff -rupN  linux-master/ linux.vanilla/ > ~/original.patch
```

Comment: Fix 3: Write your output elsewhere?